# How to convert a php array to JSON?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have the following array and i want to convert it into json format so please help me.

```
<?php

   $txt=array("apple","orange","papaya");

   json_encode($txt);

?>
```

Output :- ["apple","orange","papaya"]

```
But i want the output in the following format

[{"fruit":{"1":"apple","2":"orange","3":"papaya"}}]
```

Please help me out , i have used json_encode but i didn't got my expected result .

So , please suggest me , what will be the possible solution ?

Thanks in Advance !!!

Comment: `$txt=array("fruit" => array("1" => "apple","2" => "orange","3" => "papaya"));`

Comment: Yes but how can i generate this array format. if i am having a big array. may be 100 index.

Comment: First of all you should go inform yourself about the difference between arrays and objects.

Answer (score 0):

Simply do this:

```
<?php
   $txt=array(
           array("fruit"=>
                       array(1=> "apple",
                             2=>"orange",
                             3=>"papaya")
                   )
   );

   echo json_encode($txt);

?>
```

**output:**

```
[{"fruit":{"1":"apple","2":"orange","3":"papaya"}}]
```

[demo](https://eval.in/99155)

Comment: Yes but how can i generate this format for a bigger array ... for 100 index.

Comment: My post is an attempt to answer your question, make sure you include details and i will update my post

Comment: means i didn't understand actually , i think i have elaborated everything.. please understand and help me out.

Comment: As a side note: watch out for unicode characters. If you `json_encode` and don't see anything, chances are your text encoding is messing it up.

Comment: @user2551103 Im trying to help you out. So help me helping you. I have no context I don't know what you are trying to do, You did not elaborate about the `100index` in your question. I cant just make up the code

Comment: Also I see that you asked 7 questions and did not accept any of the many upvoted answers, its not so motivating you know.